# Is the infimum and supremum the same is greatest lower and least upper bound?

Tags: real-analysis

Everything I gather suggests the infiumum is the greatest lower bound and that the suppremum is the least upper bound, but I can't find any source to outright say that, I can only find random convoluted articles that suggest something tangential to that. Why or why aren't they the same?

Comment: Yes. This is true.

Comment: Yes, but supremum/infimum are more commonly used.

Comment: The first two paragraphs of the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum) explicitly state that they are the same.

Comment: "Consequently" is not a word I trust to be redundant, usually that means a new derivation that follows, which alludes to something new or that was unknown to me.

Comment: Yes, the are the same thing.  (But *dont* confuse them with the max or min)

Comment: ""Consequently" is not a word I trust to be redundant"  That is wise of you.  But in this particular case Wikipedia simply means that supremum *is* an upper bound.  ANd it is the *least* possible upper bound, hence it is literally the "least upper bound".

Comment: $\inf$ is often written $\operatorname{glb}$ (greatest lower bound) and $\sup$ as $\operatorname{lub}$ (least upper bound).

Comment: Why?  Because they are literally synonyms.  "least upper bound" means *literally* it is an upper bound and anything smaller is not, we define *supremum* to be precisely that: if there is an $a$ so that $a$ is an upper bound of $E$ and so that for any $b<a$ we have $b$ is not an upper bound of $E$, the we call that the *supremum* of $E$.  So the supremum of $E$ is *literally* an upper bound that is the least possible upper bound.

Answer (score 2):

**Definition:** The infimum of a (ordered) subset $S$ is the greatest element $T$ such that $T \leq s, \forall s \in S$.

**Definition:** The supremum of a (ordered) subset $S$ is the smallest element $T$ such that $T \geq s, \forall s \in S$.

That's exactly the greatest lower bound and smallest upper bound. If there's any confusion on why exactly those definitions say that please reply.

Note that it's not necessarily true that $T \in S$. Take for example the subset $S = \{q \in \mathbb{Q} : q^2 < 2\}$. This set's supremum over $\mathbb{Q}$ is not in $S$.

Comment: There's confusion in the sense that I can't find any reputable sources that say "the infimum is the greatest lower bound..." so I thought that interpretation might be wrong, but since there's multiple people confirming something that could have been a random guess, that's good enough to me.

Comment: Well if you want a legitimate source you can look at chapter 5 of Pfaffenberger and Johnsonbaugh's foundations of mathematical analysis, your uni library may have a online version (or you can *find* one). Alternatively the wikipedia page also confirms it.

Comment: "I can't find any reputable sources that say "the infimum is the greatest lower bound..." "  Walter Rudin's Principals of Mathematical Analysis" says in Chapter 1, Definition 1.8 page 4: "The *greatest lower bound*, or *infimum*, of a set E which is bounded below is defined in the same manner."  That's a reputable source.

Answer (score 0):

In situations like this, I ask myself... "What would Walter Rudin do?"

And what he very specifically did in "Principals of Mathematical Induction" Chapter 1, page 4, Definition 1.8 was define them as synonyms.

...

**1.8 Definition**  Suppose $S$ is an ordered set, $E\subset S$ and $E$ is bounded above.  Suppose there exists an $\alpha \in S$ with the following properties:

1. $\alpha$ is an upper bound of E
2. If $\gamma< \alpha$ then $\gamma$ is not an upper bound of $E$.

then $\alpha$ is called the *least upper bound of $E$* [...] or the *supremum* of $E$, and we write

$\alpha = \sup E$

The *greatest lower bound*, or *infinum*, of a set $E$ which is bounded below is defined in the same manner: The statement

$\alpha = \inf E$

means that $\alpha$ is a lower bound of $E$ and that no $\beta$ with $\beta > \alpha$ is a lower bound of $E$.